# System services for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

Can I make system services for windows phone? If yes then How? I am trying to make a system service that shows a messagebox everytime the phone is started , how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make system services on Windows Phone. The best you can do is a background agent, that will be executed once every 30 minutes. You can also, on Windows Phone 8, use the `GeoLocator` to keep your application alive in the background (it's supposed to be used only for position-tracking purpose though). But none of these workarounds allow you to react to system events, like the phone startup.